# Python3 Search an IP list and print "No Matches" if no matches. ipaddress module used

Tags: python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I have my black listed IP Addresses in one file and my test IP Addresses in another. If my test IP addresses match an IP in my black listed IP file. I it prints out the IP and what black listed .txt if was found in.

My problem is when the IPs do not match. I would like it to print out "NO Matches" once, but it skips this part or prints it out for every none matching IP. Its no big deal other than its driving me nuts that I cant figure it out and it probably really simple.

I'm using the ipaddress module because I also search IP addresses with subnets. I have tried every loop I can think of, but I'm out of ideas.

```
import os, sys
import ipaddress
import re

IPsToTest = open('IP_We_Want_TO_Scan.txt','r').readlines()   

BadIPFiles = []
for i in os.listdir('BadIPAddresses\\'):
    if i.endswith(".txt"):
        BadIPFiles.append(str(i))

""" Single IP Scanning Function """
def CheckSingleIP():
    for SingleFileName in BadIPFiles:
        with open('BadIPAddresses\\' + SingleFileName) as MainTest:
            REGNetIP = re.findall('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', MainTest.read())
            for n in REGNetIP:
                for IPs in IPsToTest:
                    IPs = IPs.strip()
                    IPs = ipaddress.ip_address(IPs)
                    n = ipaddress.ip_address(n)
                    """ Print IPs matching black lists """ 
                    while True:  
                        if IPs == n:
                            print("\nMatched in {0}  - IP Address {1}".format(SingleFileName,IPs))
                            break
                        else:
                            if IPs is not n:
                                break
                            print("[+] Great! No Matches! [+]")
                        break

CheckSingleIP()
print("\n\n - - - - - - Finished Scanning - - - - - - !\n")
```

The 'else:' is what I cant get to work. It does print out "Finished Scanning" but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a boolean variable called something like 'MatchFound' at the start of your loop, set to False. If a match is found, set it to True.
Then at the end of your loop, run a check on the boolean, if it is set to True, print your "[+] Great! No Matches! [+]".